# Table [tablename] could not be found -2147189180

Tags: sql-server, vb6, crystal-reports

I have created a report using Crystal Reports XIr2 to report on information from a database for our application. It is a cross tab report, reporting on a variety of data returned from running a stored procedure.

A quick bit about the application that this report is run through - it is an application written in VB6, upon loading the application you are prompted for a username and password, which are configured on a SQL server as SQL logins, so when you log into the application you are authenticating against SQL server security.

The report is working absolutely fine in Crystal Reports, however I am experiencing some weird behaviour with this report when it is launched from within our application on a customer site. It works fine for all users with 'sa' level database access but gives the following error when run as any other user;

[image: Error message]

If I connect to the database server directly as a user that gets the above error within the application, running the stored procedures manually works without any errors.

If I give a user that is getting the error within our application 'sa' permissions on the SQL server, the error stops happening.

I have checked all related execute permissions for the stored procedure in question, but as stated if I connect to the SQL Server manually and execute the procedure, I do not get the error linked above.

If the user who is getting this error runs another report before this report, it works, however if they run a report after getting this error, all reports stop working and require an application restart.

Any ideas please?

Comment: Please open the report in Crystal and find the affected table in Field Explorer.  Right Click the table, and select "Set Datasource Location...".  Expand the tree beneath the affected table, and view its properties.

Who is the owner?

Comment: Does the stored procedure do any WRITING to the database at all?  Or is it just running `Select` statements?  Assuming you have access to the SQL Server; in the database properties>Permissions, does the user or roles trying to run the procedure have any permissions?

Comment: Does the database associated with this table have any unusual characters in it, perchance? And is competenceReport truly a table, as the error message indicates, or a stored procedure, as you suggest in the problem text?

Comment: The stored procedure only reads from the database - as pointed out in my question if I connect to the SQL server using SQL Management Studio I can successfully execute the stored procedure as the user who receives the error when running the report through our application, so the user in question has the permissions to run the procedure.

Comment: If possible, I'd suggest you run SQL Profiler against the target database to see if more information on the failure can be seen on the database side..

Comment: This is starting to sounds more like a vb problem and less SQL/CR... Is there anything complex going on with the VB code that might be causing the problem?  Can you post any of the VB code?

Comment: The code in question is nothing special or complex, and works for the other reports within the system. It is unlikely that I am going to be allowed to post any of it online though but will continue with this from the point of view that it's probably VB contributing to the issue more than anything on the SQL instance.

Comment: Are you using Crystal 10??  If so, please see the following link: [ftp://ftp.ca.com/caproducts/CertReleaseKit/SPECTRUM/07.01.00/CrystalV10/ce10_hotfix_srn_sp3.pdf](ftp://ftp.ca.com/caproducts/CertReleaseKit/SPECTRUM/07.01.00/CrystalV10/ce10_hotfix_srn_sp3.pdf)
See top of page 16 for hotfix

If not using 10, please post versions of Crystal and SQL Server

Comment: I only asked above because it could have been an "L" or a typo.  If it is definitely ELEVEN, try changing this registry key on the server : `[Software\Business Objects\Suite 11.5\Crystal Reports\Database\ODBC]
"AccessMode"=dword:00000000 `  Note what it was so you can change it back if it didn't work.

Comment: It is definitely XI R2, I will test the registry change tomorrow (as I'm no longer in the office) - ta

Comment: @XToro this key doesn't exist on either our client site or my own machine, should I create it or is the lack of existence essentially the same as a zero value in this instance?

Comment: @pixel It should exist on a machine where Crystal Reports is installed, either under `HKEY_Local_Machine` or `HKEY_Current_User`...  The lack of the value doesn't mean the program considers it a zero value as the default for the program might be something other than zero.  Check the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Business Objects\Suite 11.5\Crystal Reports\Database\ODBC` part of the registry

Comment: Yeah I'm missing the AccessMode dword, have the rest of the key upto and including ODBC but no AccessMode under either HKLM or HKCU

Comment: How about if you grant "View Definition" permission to the Stored Procedure.

Comment: Does the identity that the report is running under on the server have access to the tables? Is the users' identity being passed or is it a server principal?

Comment: Are you getting this error on development environment also? if no then its the issue of sql server version on the client server. i faced similar issue with one of my clients and re-installing sql server using same setup that was used in my development environment solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you make sure the default schema of the user mapping for the database is set to dbo for the users reporting the issue. I also recommend using database roles for that.

Answer (score 0):

Granting execute permission doesn't always end there -- At times, you'll have to check the possible permission blocks of the objects within. When you say that you used the user's login to run the procedure manually, is it also for certain that the user's credentials are what you use to connect to the database?

Perhaps you can use a more universal sql login that the application will use -- this way you won't have to keep track of permissions for multiple users (just a suggestion! :) )